# Ангулар проблема с директивой

Tags: javascript, angular

Хочу узнать как можно прописать скрипт внутри OnInit более надежным способом. Спасибо за помощь!

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appTimeStamp]'
    })
    export class TimeStampDirective implements OES_element_index_uint {
    
      @Input('appTimeStamp') time!: string;
    
      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        let timeSpan: HTMLSpanElement = this.renderer.createElement('span');
        timeSpan.innerText = this.getTimestamp(this.time);
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, timeSpan);
      }
    
      getTimestamp = (time: string) => {
        console.log(time);
        var sec = Date.parse(time) / 1000;
        var min = sec / 60;
        var hour = min / 60;
        var day = Math.floor(hour / 24) + ' дней ' + Math.floor(hour % 24) + ' часов ' + Math.floor(min % 60) + ' минут';
        return day;
      };
    }
```

Comment: Что значит "надежным способом"? И что должно быть на выходе? Кол-во дней, часов и секунд прошедших с начала 1970 года?

Comment: Выводит в таком формате 0 дней 0 часов 40 минут. Тоесть сколько дней назад был зарегистрирован. хотел бы узнать можно ли заменить скрипт в ngOnInit? сделать по другому чтоли

Comment: А не проще для этого использовать пайп, а не директиву?

Comment: А в чём будет плюс использования пайпов вместо директивы?

Comment: Пайпы нужны, чтобы манипулировать данными, например теми же строками. Директивы нужны, чтобы манипулировать DOM элементов. к которым они привязаны. В вашем случае лезть в DOM не обязательно, вам просто нужно преобразовать строку в нужный вид. Если вам интересна реализация через пайп, могу показать ее в ответе.

Comment: Буду очень признателен сенсей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно преобразовать строку например такого вида `2022-07-22T22:26:23+0000`(дата в формате ISO 8601), то лучше использовать `Pipe`.

Использовать `Directive` будет излишним, т.к это лишние манипуляции с DOM, что замедлит рендеринг. Вам же не нужно менять стили или добавлять какие-то элементы.

В Angular `Pipe` предназначен для трансформации данных. В [документации](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) написано:

> `Pipes` — это простые функции, которые можно использовать в шаблоне, чтобы принимать входное значение и возвращать преобразованное значение. `Pipes` полезны тем, что вы можете использовать их во всем приложении, объявляя каждый  только один раз.

Так вы сможете преобразовать строку `2022-07-22T22:26:23+0000` в удобный вам вид, например в `0 дней 20 часов 9 минут`.

Для этого создадим пайп командой:

```
ng g p timestamp
```

Angular CLI создаст файл `timestamp.pipe.ts` и добавит `TimestampPipe` в `AppModule`.

**timestamp.pipe.ts**

```typescript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timestamp',
})
export class TimestampPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    const sec = (Date.now() - Date.parse(value)) / 1000;
    const min = sec / 60;
    const hour = min / 60;
    return (
      Math.floor(hour / 24) +
      ' дней ' +
      Math.floor(hour % 24) +
      ' часов ' +
      Math.floor(min % 60) +
      ' минут'
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<p>{{ dateString | timestamp }}</p>
```

Ссылка на [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8c1j68?file=src/app/timestamp.pipe.ts), где показана работа и директивы и пайпа в одном компоненте.

Comment: Благодарю очень ясно и понятно разъяснили.